# How do you make two Android apps share the same user id?

Tags: java, android

I remember reading somewhere that you could make two android apps share the same user id, but I have heard conflicting information from other people. Is it possible to make two apps share the same user id and if so how is it done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you can with the [sharedUserId](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#sharedUserId) manifest attribute. The two apps have to also be signed with the same signature.

Answer (score 3):

When you have the same sharedUserId (in you manifests) and two apps are signed with the same certificate, you can use this snippet to access the file from your other app:

```
Context ctx = createPackageContext("com.yourcompany.youapp", CONTEXT_RESTRICTED);
FileInputStream fis = ctx.openFileInput("sharedFile.txt");
```